# An easy trick/Way to modify parameter value of a section in INI file in Perl

Tags: perl, parameters, ini

I'm looking for An easy trick/Way to modify paramter value of a section in INI file in Perl, as you may know, all parameter in INI file have the same name (that's its big problem), only the section name can make the difference, but I don't think that it will help in my case:

Section1

param1=s1value1

param2=val1

Section2

param1=s2value2

param2=val2

Section3

param1=s3value3

param2=val3

I want to change value val2 of parameter param2 of Section2 to valN, Any idea, I looked on module on CPAN, but module needs module and so on, I never had it working, I think that there is an easy way hein?

Comment: Are you sure the sections aren't `[Section1]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [Config::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/Config-Tiny/lib/Config/Tiny.pm):

```
use Config::Tiny;

my $filename = "test.ini";
my $config = Config::Tiny->new();
$config = Config::Tiny->read($filename);
print "Before:\n";
print $config->write_string();

$config->{Section2}->{param2} = 'valN'; 
print "After:\n";
print $config->write_string();

$config->write($filename);
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a non-standard INI file, which would have sections indicated by square brackets: `[Section Name]`. However, a line not containing an equals sign is easy enough a specification.

So here's a sub that hunts down the section and keyname and changes the value.

```
sub new_ini_value { 
    my ( $input, $output, $section, $keyname, $new_value ) = @_;
    my $curr_sect = '';
    SEARCH:
    while ( <$input> ) { 
        if ( m/^\s*([^=]*?)\s*$/ ) { 
            $curr_sect = $1;
        }
        elsif ( $curr_sect eq $section )  { 
            my ( $key, $value ) = m/^\s*([^=]*[^\s=])\s*=\s*(.*?\S)\s*$/;
            if ( $key and $key eq $keyname  ) { 
                print $output "$keyname=$new_value\n";
                last SEARCH;
            }
        }
        print $output $_;
    }
    use English qw<$RS>;
    local $RS;
    print $output ( <$input> );
}
```